# Custom message generated C , Python and Lisp code location

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm following the tutorial here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Common_step_for_msg_and_srv .

I created the package in the previous tutorial.  My catkin_ws is in a different location than used in the tutorial though.  Mine is in a dropbox folder (~/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials).

When I execute catkin_make (step 4 in the tutorial),

```
~/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- beginner_tutorials: 2 messages, 1 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/benjaminblumer/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  9%] [ 18%] Generating Lisp code from beginner_tutorials/Num.msg
Generating C++ code from beginner_tutorials/Num.msg
[ 27%] Generating Python from MSG beginner_tutorials/Num
[ 54%] [ 54%] [ 63%] Built target beginner_tutorials_genlisp
Generating Python msg __init__.py for beginner_tutorials
Generating Python srv __init__.py for beginner_tutorials
[ 81%] Built target beginner_tutorials_genpy
[100%] Built target beginner_tutorials_gencpp
```

The tutorial says this should generate a folder called msg_gen in the package folder.  This directory doesn't appear to exist anywhere.
However, under catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg there is a _Num.py file.  Is this the expected behaviour?  It'd be much nicer for the generated files to be in the same directory as all of the code I've been writing -- the catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials directory. Can this be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62625/custom-message-generated-c--,-python-and-lisp-code-location/) by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the tutorial is a bit out of date for the Groovy release.  If using a `catkin` workspace, and `catkin_make` to build, then the C++ message definition should be in *~/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/Bablumer/trunk/catkin_ws/devel/include/beginner_tutorials*, and the Python message definition should be exactly where you found it.  This isn't really in inconvenience thanks to the internal workings of `catkin_make`, and the `setup.bash` files that are provided in your workspace.  If you `#include` the C++ file in a piece of source code, as long as the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` files are correct, then catkin will know how to find that file.  The same is true for importing modules in Python.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2013-05-13**:
Using python, what should the `import` command look like to have it find that file?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-05-14**:
Just like in the following tutorial... it should look something like `import rospy` followed by `from beginner_tutorials.msg import Num`

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2013-05-14**:
Thanks! I've updated the tutorial page to reflect your answer.